# What is the url for the Cumulative update package 3 for 64bit SQL Server 2008 SP1

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is Cumulative update package 3 for SQL Server 2008 SP1 available for 64 bit SQL server?

I couldnt find the link.
Please advice.

Thanks-
Manjot

Comment: Belongs on serverfault? How is not finding a link related to programming?

Comment: I just know about stackoverflow.com and saw :
serverfault.com | superuser.com | howtogeek.com | meta 

in the footer of this website. So, are they all inter-related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Heres the link.](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=971491&kbln=en-us)

If you don't see 64-bit there, you might see this instead:

> Step 1   Show hotfixes for all
>   platforms and languages (10)

Click that to show all downloads.

Comment: Thanks. Out of the following: 


SQL_Server_2008_SP1_Cumulative_Update_3_RS_Sharepo 2008,


SQL_Server_2008_SP1_Cumulative_Update_3_RBClickOnc 2008,


SQL_Server_2008_SP1_Cumulative_Update_3_SNAC 2008,


SQL_Server_2008_SP1_Cumulative_Update_3 2008 10.00.2723.00,


I should be interested only in last one. Am I right?

Comment: I believe any of them will work, so the last one should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [View and Requests Hotfix Downloads](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=960484&kbln=en-us) link on [KB 960484](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960484).

Comment: I don't think those downloads are for SP1.

Comment: No, they're for CU3, as the OP requested

Comment: I meant they're not for Service Pack 1, theres a CU3 for RTM and one for SP1.

Answer (score 0):

I logged into the URL using Xp 32 bit, and saw a message that said something like, "We detected that you are on a 32bit platform". I suspect that what happens is that it only gives you "BIT Version" links based on the platform you logged into the page (which is silly, and contrary to the way other service packs are accessed). For example if you log in on a Windows 7 64 bit platform, if my assumption is correct, you would see links to the 64 bit fixes.

So I am going to configure my Host Virtual server "safely" so I can login to the page from my server and browse on this 64 bit platform and hopefully see the links to the cummulative service fixes for 64 bit platform.

BigHamp